# PHP preg_replace replace '/ /' with '/'

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace all occurrences of `'/ /'` in a string with `'/'`.  I can't seem to find the right regex expression to match the string to replace, however.

Currently, I have `preg_replace('/\/\s\//', '/', $string);` but this does not replace any occurrences of `'/ /'`.

To be clear, I would like to match any occurrences of a forward slash followed by whitespace followed by a forward slash.  It seems that the last forward slash messes things up.  I have also tried `str_replace()`, but to no avail.

EDIT: 
The regex expression works correctly if I run it on a string like so:
`echo(preg_replace('/\/\s?\//m', '/', ".... . -.-- / / .... ---"));` and I get the output: `.... . -.-- / .... ---`.  But when I run it like this: 
`$morse = preg_replace('/\/\s?\//m', '/', $morse);` The replacement does not work.  For the record, the ouput of `echo($morse)` before preg_replace is `.... . -.-- / / .... ---` and after it is the exact same.  I have no idea what could be causing this, some sort of weird encoding in the $morse variable string?

<s>Please help, this is driving me crazy.  Thanks in advance!</s>

Comment: It's unclear why this wouldn't work. Maybe you are misjudging the input string? If you want a useful answer, a realistic sample of your source $string would make sense.

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/TWkVl

Comment: it's working fine check here https://regex101.com/r/YLdut1/1

Comment: If it's a normal space and it will always look the same, you don't need regex. Just do:  `$string = str_replace('/ /', '/', $string);`

Comment: I updated my post with a realistic (actual) $string @mario

Comment: I don't see any issue with this echo $morse = preg_replace('/\/\s?\//m', '/', $morse);

Its working as your requirement.

Comment: "the ouput of `echo($morse)`" is still insufficient for diagnosis. You never mentioned its source or context. First of all, use var_dump() or provide a side-by-side plain/hexdump. If you are looking at this through a browser window (= html context) you'll be none the wiser if the spacing is a single space character, nbsp, or linebreaks in between. If looking at view-source or running your code on the CLI doesn't reveal the culprit, then update your question again. Use a code block (not inline code) to showcase the raw string. (And also edit out the subtly striked-through "please help" part).

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern you have written is correct and it will replace if the `/ /` occurrence is found. I updated your `pattern` to `/\/\s?\//m`. You can [**try**](https://regex101.com/r/Bc3XHV/2) the following way.

```
$re = '/\/\s?\//m';
$str = 'test string // test string / /';
$subst = '/';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Comment: OP clearly states they want whitespace between the `/`. `/\s?/` will match `//`.

Answer (score 0):

The use of other delimiters would simplify things enormously here:

```
$regex = '~/\s+/~';
$replacement = '/';

$string = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $original_string);
```

Note, that your original string is left untouched.